# Linking with MySQL and C++

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I followed each step outlined within the MySQL C++ Connector and I keep getting the error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32 referenced in function on build. How can I connect with MySQL using C++?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the reference to a lib. Make sure all the libs that came with the MySQL C++ Connector are referenced and included in the project (settings).

Comment: I added the MySQL/include directory to additional include directories. I added lib/opt to additional library. Added  mysqlcppconn-static.lib and libmysql.lib to additional dependancies. Set CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC= in c++ preprocessor. In source code I include <my_global.h> and <mysql.h>. I don't see what I could be missing.

Comment: Are you including x64 libs for an x32 application or vice versa by any chance?

Comment: No the libraries look like they are all in order.